# html web page on android

Tags: html, mobile, web

There is a simple web page (dance-dome.com http://jsfiddle.net/maxgister/95Zhn/) It displays correctly on computers and iOS devices, but not on Android. (Background image is not extended.)
I tried to use media-queries for mobile version, but there is no result. What's the problem?

```
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
background:url(http://dance-dome.com/images/11.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: url(http://dance-dome.com/images/11.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background:url(http://dance-dome.com/images/11.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
-moz-background-size:100% 100%;
-o-background-size:100% 100%;
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: Updated again. Try that. Android might not recognize "cover"

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. 
Result - http://cs617920.vk.me/v617920112/e379/NHSoVH5wzB4.jpg

Comment: That means that either body is not being set correctly or html is not expanding to the full width of the screen